# What happens when returning a procedure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return, procedure

Defining a 'procedure' (if this isn't already the accepted definition) as a function/'subroutine' without a return value (so it's undefined, I guess), such as:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('something');
}
```

What happens in something like this:

```
function a() {
    if (somecondition) {
        return foo();
    }
    // more statements, but no return statement
}
a();
```

As far as I can tell, someone who would write this just doesn't want to use an `else` and instead uses the fact that returning from a function prevents the rest from being executed. Is this right? Is there a preferred practice?

Is the line `return foo()` just syntactic sugar for `foo(); return;`, since `return foo();` == `return undefined;` == `return;`? Is this a bad practice, because it isn't exactly clear that the value of `foo()` is `undefined`?

At a very low level, what would happen to the return value `undefined`? `a()` would just evaluate to `undefined` and then exist on the stack frame of the parent or global scope as an unassigned value, right? And then it would be garbage collected soon after?

Would this be any different if function `a` returned a non-undefined value, like `2`?

Comment: I think you mean `return foo`

Comment: No, I really don't. Maybe the title should read 'the result of a procedure call' instead? I don't know why you think this.

Comment: "Is the line `return foo()` just syntactic sugar for `foo(); return`" then no, because there is no way of knowing that the value of `foo()` is undefined before runtime.

Comment: Why do you need to know the value of `foo()` before runtime?

Comment: If `foo` has a return value then `foo(); return` is not the same as `return foo()`. The kind of syntactic sugar you are mentioning not only does not exist, but _cannot_ because you would have to determine that `foo()` is undefined before runtime.

Comment: But the supposition was that `foo` is a procedure? In that case, they are functionally equivalent aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When *function* `a` is executing and encounters `return foo()`, the following takes place:

1. *function* `a` should be paused
2. a new execution context should be created for *function* `foo` on top of the execution stack
3. *function* `foo` should execute within that new execution context
4. *function* `foo`, itself, does not contain any `return` statements and so,  the function will run to completion (assuming there are no errors).
5. the execution context for `foo` will be removed from the call stack and all local variables will be de-referenced (assuming that there are no closures preventing this).
6. execution control will return to *function* `a` where it left off (`return foo()`)
7. since *function* `foo` did not return a value, *function* `a` executes its `return` statement but with a value of `undefined` being returned to the caller of *function* `a`.
8. the execution context for *function* `a` is removed from the call stack and all of its local variables are de-referenced (assuming there are no closures preventing it).

> Is the line `return foo()` just syntactic sugar for `foo(); return;`,
>   since return `foo(); == return undefined; == return;`? Is this a bad
>   practice, because it isn't exactly clear that the value of foo() is
>   undefined?

Would `return foo()` (when `foo()` returns `undefined`) would amount to: `foo(); return;`, but that doesn't mean that this syntax is "syntactic sugar", it is incorrect syntax that implies that the code is doing one thing, when, in fact, it does something else. This coding style should **not** be used. Remember, in all of programming, the best-practice is "make code readable". This syntax, when most read it, would cause us to immediatley believe the code is broken as it implies you want to do something (return a value to the caller) that it clearly doesn't do.

**Note**: All de-referenced identifiers are immediately available for garbage collection since they are not being assigned anywhere.

**Summary**: A function does not take on the value of its return value, that value is simply passed to the caller and it is for the caller to determine what to do with it.

Even if `foo` did return a value, your code is:

```
a();
```

Which does not capture the return value coming out of `a()` so that value would be immediately garbage collected because it is not being stored anywhere.

However, if you had written:

```
var x = a();
```

Then the `undefined` value would persist in the `x` variable for as long as `x` remains in scope.

The only reason to use `return` in a function is to terminate the function early (a `return` all by itself will do this) or to terminate execution but do it while passing an "output" parameter of sorts to the caller. If you have a function that is purely procedural (that is, it does work but does not produce a value result), there is no reason to include `return`. In fact, the unnecessary use of `return` is discouraged as it makes the code more difficult to read and introduces the possibility of bugs due to a misunderstanding of the code's intent.

Comment: I did recognise all these points in my question, the question was more about what happens low-level and whether or not it's syntactic sugar.

Comment: I mean, the `// more statements, but no return statment` bit *would* be reached if `somecondition` is falsy.

Comment: @sidney That's true, but you really should not take advantage of optional curly braces in an `if/then/else` branch as it invites bugs later on.

Comment: Oh god, I just realised I was missing the close bracket of the if clause, so hopefully it makes a bit more sense now. So with your last paragraph, I was wondering whether using a return inside an if clause (like `if (somecondition) { return procedure();} // do more stuff`) would be better or worse than `if (somecondition) { procedure();} else { // do more stuff}`. So in the former, return *isn't* unnecessary, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice.

Comment: Again, only use `return` if you wish to terminate the execution of the current function (so, maybe in your true branch of your `if` statement, if your logic does not require the rest of the function to run, `return` would make sense). Or, use `return` if you need to get a result passed out off the function (but, again understand that this will terminate the function, so in those cases, the `return` is usually placed at the bottom of all needed code. Barring those two scenarios, adding `return` clutters the code and should not be used. `return` should not be used as a coding style.

Comment: If `procedure()` doesn't return a value, writing `return procedure();` makes no sense.

Comment: But the thing is we *want* the `// do more stuff` bit to not run when `somecondition` is truthy. I agree that `return procedure();` makes no semantic sense, but I've seen it used and want to know if I should use that or `procedure(); return;` or just skip the `return;` and use an `else` clause.

Comment: In this use case, you should write `procedure(); return;` because that is clear as to your intent.

Comment: Any references for that?

Comment: Personally, no. But, code that does what it is intended to do and is clear (and more importantly doesn't imply a behavior that wasn't intended) is a well-known coding best practice. https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/writing-elegant-and-readable-code--mobile-21514 and if you've got a lot of time  on your hands: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS606US606&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=code%20should%20clear%20and%20readable

Comment: As a matter of fact, look at the very first comment you got on your question. The user believed you had a mistake in your logic because it is clear that `foo` doesn't return a value, yet you wrote `return foo();`.

Comment: What about something like `if (err) {return console.error(err);} // non error code`. One could argue that it's obvious what it's doing, and to do otherwise would be wasting a line.

Comment: Same answer as before. It's not about the style of coding this, it's about what is the code supposed to do. `console.error()` does not return a value and so, putting a `return` in front of it is misleading. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you see

```
return foo();
```

but it is meant to be a short writing of

```
foo();
return;
```

If `foo` does not return something, then both versions work, but only the first returns the value from `foo`, the second returns the default value of `undefined`.

Comment: I kinda knew this, but was wondering if this is an accepted/good practice? Because `return foo();`, when `foo` does not return something, is a bit semantically misleading, imo.

Comment: it is more code golf, but not good practice, because you return something which should not be returned, even if it works.

Comment: I'd agree with you, but are there any references for this being a bad practice?